# Django error, constantly faced with the same server error even if I start an entirely new application and run it

Tags: django

> OperationalError at /
>   no such table: core_document
>   Request Method: GET
>   Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
>   Django Version: 2.1.4
>   Exception Type: OperationalError
>   Exception Value:
>   no such table: core_document
>   Exception Location: C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute, line 296
>   Python Executable:  C:\Python37-32\python.exe
>   Python Version: 3.7.1
>   Python Path:
>   ['E:\Django\Dec19\simple-file-upload-master',
>    'C:\Python37-32\python37.zip',
>    'C:\Python37-32\DLLs',
>    'C:\Python37-32\lib',
>    'C:\Python37-32',
>    'C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages']
>   Server time:    Wed, 19 Dec 2018 04:22:57 +0000

Comment: did you migrated the DB?

Comment: Do the migrations before running server. Check out the official doc for a clear idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run migrations:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

The first line of the error explains the core issue:

```
OperationalError at / no such table: core_document
```

The table which is being referenced doesn't exist. This usually happens when migrations haven't successfully run. To begin troubleshooting (and to possibly fix the problem entirely), run the [Django migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/migrations/):

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```